# Get row value of checked row in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have painted a datatable with checkbox's against each row. Now when i select certain checkboxes and click submit , I want to get the value of all the columns in the entire row.

I tried using `$('tr input',oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();` , but this returned only the value of the checkbox. 
How can i get the value of the entire checked row.

Comment: this SO link may help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678624/how-to-capture-the-data-in-a-selected-row-using-jquery-datatables/5678778#5678778

Comment: What do you mean with 'value of the entire checked row.'?Can you provide an example and the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue.

Looped over each of the `tr` rows in the Datatables, and got the an array containing value of each cell using

```
$('#DataTable tr').each(function() {    
          var rowData = this.cells
```

rowData is an array which contains the values of each of the cells.Since the checkbox was the first column , got the value of the first column from the rowData array like this

```
rowData[0].firstChild.value
```